# Struts2 session timeout intercepter not working

Tags: session, timeout, interceptor

Hi friends am new bee in struts2 i am developing application in which i have used session timeout interceptor, My Problem is timeout is not happening below is link from which i have referred the code 
    http://knowledge-serve.blogspot.in/2011/10/session-timeout-interceptor-in-struts-2.html

This problem may be because i have some javascript which continously running to refresh list.
Or may be i am wrong but this session is not expiring

please help me 
thank u

Answer (score 0):

```
<interceptors>
       <interceptor name="SessionCheckInterceptor"  class="com.vicwalks.web.interceptor.SessionCheckInterceptor"/>        
      <interceptor-stack name="testSessionValidationStack">
                <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />               
                <interceptor-ref name="SessionCheckInterceptor" />
      </interceptor-stack> 

</interceptors>
```

In `struts.xml` sequence of interceptor is important.Try to change the sequence of `defaultStack and SessionCheckInterceptor`.Because in your code `defaultstack` wont called first.Since you wont get `sessionMap` object in `sessionCheckInterceptor`.

Answer (score 0):

As MayurB rightly pointed out, you just need to swap the stack. You can also use

```
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) context.get(HTTP_REQUEST);
HttpSession httpSession = request.getSession(false);
```

This will be available before defaultStack